# Is there a way to tell the user that the input is wrong?

Tags: python, sql-server

How can I code in a way that it tells my user that the input not available in the database?

Here is my code:

```
def sql_getage(name):
    query = """\
        select age from store
        where name = '{}'
        """.format(name)
    results = (execute_read_query (conn, query))
    for i in results:
        theresult = str(i[0])
    return (theresult)
name = input("Please input your username")
age = sql_getage(name)
print("Your age is", age)
```

My database have 2 columns:

```
username    Age
John        20
Amy         21
```

How can I code such that if the user inputs name as
`Jhn`, And it cannot be found in the database table, then I would print `wrong username`

Currently if I input the name wrongly, it will still continue to the next code, which is printing the age. And it would print an empty age.

Comment: Perhaps your function should return the `results` variable and then your existing code could examine it to see how many results were returned.

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name is not found, `results` will be an empty list.  Your function can check for this, and in that case return `None` instead:

```
results = (execute_read_query (conn, query))
if not results:
    return None
```

Then in the calling code, you can check for a `None` return value:

```
age = sql_getage(name)
if age is None:
    print("Name not found")
else:
    print("Your age is", age)
```

Also, please change your query to set the name value with *parameters* instead of string formatting.  You're leaving yourself wide open for an SQL injection attack.